# Text inserted into table Cell , A clickable URL link?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Text inserted into table Cell , A clickable URL link ?

I have a table that that holds three values FROM , MESSAGE , DATE-TIME

The message cell is in the following format

```
 echo '<table class="table table-fixed  table-bordered table-hover">';

 echo "<tr><th>From</th><th>Message</th><th>Time-Date</th></tr><tr>"; 

 echo $row['message'];

 echo "</td><td>";
```

AS shown below I have made the cell FROM a clickable link

```
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo "<a href=message.php?id=".$senerid.">Reply to : </a>";
echo $row['username']; // username of sender
echo "</td><td>";
```

Which allows the users that views to click the link, However I want the link to be clickable that is send as part of the message like below example

[image]

Im sending the message as automated response to a friend request

```
$link = "http://accept.php";
echo '<a href="' . $link . '">Accept</a>';

$message = "you have a new friend request  ".$link." Accept"  ;
$sqll = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `inbox` (`message` , `username` ,   `userid` , `rcpuser`, `senderid`, `time` ) VALUES ('".$message."', '".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."', '".$me."','".$q."','".$me."' , now() )");
```

How can this be made possible please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to build?

Comment: Any image your idea

Comment: Trying to make the link clickable above in the message cell that is part of the message , As shown $link is the URL but when the receiver opens the message the link is not clickable //accept.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `<a>` tag in a variable like below and append that variable into message, see below:

`$clickable_link = '<a href="' . $link . '">Accept</a>'`

`$message = "you have a new friend request  ".$clickable_link;`

**Edit:** While sending an email you might require to set headers.

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: you can omit the second "Accept" let only the one in the link.

Comment: Thanks . Working Now . Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your link in an html link with

```
$link = '<a href="' . $link . '">Accept</a>';
```

And include it in the message with your code.

I would also check if there is a cleaning function on your link, like `htmlentities()` or `strip-tags()` this would either delete or replace the html tag with plain text and prevent the "clickability" of your link afterwards.

Comment: Certainly will do so and thanks for the helpful advice .